# Date column detected as VarChar by SQL Server Import Wizard

Tags: excel, date-formatting, sql-import-wizard

I am trying to import an Excel document into SQL Server 2012. However, for some reason some Date type columns from Excel are automatically detected as VarChar by the SQL Server Import Wizard and I get an error when importing as the destination columns are all datetime. In the below image, the first column gets detected as "Date Time" but the second and third get detected as "VarChar", but I can't see any difference and the columns all say "Date" in Excel. What are some possible causes and solutions for this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The likely cause is that if there are a lot of missing values at the top of the dates column then SQL Server will default to VarChar. According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141683.aspx), it looks at the first 8 rows.

A workaround which I have used is just to insert a dummy date in the first row and delete it later.